# PHP Grab a certain word and ignore the rest in a string

Tags: php, regex, strpos

I am trying to grab only usernames in a list of sentences of about 30 lines long. I am able to get it to grab the usernames and everything afterwards but I dont want to get everything after the username.

test.txt

```
[India] Hagiwara has been inactive for 33 days (last seen: Sun Jan 25 23:35:35 2015).
[India] Psyborg has been inactive for 35 days (last seen: Fri Jan 23 18:43:58 2015).
[Echo] Pela has been inactive for 31 days (last seen: Tue Jan 27 20:00:30 2015).
```

PHP

```
$data = file('test.txt');

foreach ($data as $lines) {

if (($pos = strpos($lines, "]")) !== FALSE) { 
    $string = substr($lines, $pos+1); 
}

echo $string . '<br />';
}
```

Output

```
Hagiwara has been inactive for 33 days (last seen: Sun Jan 25 23:35:35 2015).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be more than you expected, but here is a way to avoid regex.

```
$string = substr($lines, $pos+2);
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ' '));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$username = explode(' ',$lines)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your example strings and based on the assumption that a username will never contain whitespace characters:

```
<?php
$input_line = "[India] Hagiwara has been inactive for 33 days (last seen: Sun Jan 25 23:35:35 2015).";
if (preg_match("/\[.+\]\s*(\S+)\s*.*/", $input_line, $output_array) == 1) {
    echo $output_array[1];
}
?>
```

Will print out "Hagiwara".

Answer (score 0):

The Regex to do this isn't so complicated.  It's more bulletproof imho

`$str1 = '[India] Hagiwara has been inactive for 33 days (last seen: Sun Jan 25 23:35:35 2015).';`

`$str2 = '[India] Psyborg has been inactive for 35 days (last seen: Fri Jan 23 18:43:58 2015).';`

`$str3 = '[Echo] Pela has been inactive for 31 days (last seen: Tue Jan 27 20:00:30 2015).';`

`$strs = array($str1,$str2,$str3);`

`foreach ($strs as $key => $val) {`

```
  //strips the initial bracketed string from the beginning of the line
  $trimmed_val = preg_replace("/^\[\w+\]\s/",'',$val);

  //grabs the first word from the trimmed string (user in this case)
  preg_match("/^\w+\s/",$trimmed_val,$users);

  //prints out a list of users for demonstration
  echo $users[0] . '<br/>';
```

`}`